# Installing ngResource in Factory

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to install ngResource into a factory like so:

```
'use strict';
var DTapp = angular.module('DeviceTraining');
/* Services */

DTapp.factory('Slides', ['ngResource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('slides/:slideID.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{slideID:'slides'}, isArray: true}
    });
}]);
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngResourceProvider <- ngResource <- Slides
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you install modules. You include `ngResource` in your module and inject `$resource` into your factory:

```
var DTapp = angular.module('DeviceTraining', ['ngResource']);
DTapp.factory('Slides', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
   // ...
}]);
```

Comment: Okay when I do that I get this error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`  I've changed all instances of myApp to DTapp.  When I cloned the angular-seed app does it somehow have a myApp reference in ngResource or something?  Thanks!

Comment: Check your html what is declared for `ng-app`

Comment: Its declared as `<html lang="en" ng-app="DeviceTraining">`

Comment: Hm, looks like it's still loading `myApp` somewhere. Have you tried using only the files you really need? `myApp` shouldn't be defined in ngResource.

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap and I hadn't realized it uses an index.js file that referenced `myApp`.  Got that fixed.  Now when I try MannyD's answer I get this: `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: Okay... so I think I got it figured out.  I had a few problems going on.  First as MannyD pointed out I was not injecting $resource correctly.  Second, PhoneGap bootstrapped angular and I missed that.  Third, I didn't source the ngResource script.  Thanks everyone!